# Want to get list of Cloud SQL instance in multiple projects in current organisation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-apis-explorer

I am a fresher to GCP and i would like know how do we get all details related to list of Cloud SQL instances ( Including MYSQL, POSTGRESSSQL, SQLSERVER) from multiple projects in my current organisation.

The purpose of this is to design a dashboard to see various metrics like number of instances running, number of databases running etc. Please note that the default metrics in monitoring does not have these features

**Please let me know in detail on how to get on this requirement**

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. First rule: do not ask someone to do your research or job for you. You must show your effort to solve your problem. Start with these two guides: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask AND https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Asset Inventory product](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory). With GCLOUD cli, you can do that like this

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=organizations/<YourOrgID> \
  --asset-types='sqladmin.googleapis.com/Instance'
```

If you want to create dashboard, I recommend you to [export assets to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-bigquery)